# Cannot index into a null array error when value is not null

Tags: powershell, sql-job

I am using Poweshell to view the status of specific SQL job.
I want to pass job name as input like read-host or pass through variable.
The script works fine when job name is static string in qoutes(Script 1) .In case I pass it through variable, it does not work.

If I loop through each job in Jobs and compare the job name with where-object comparison to string it works fine. That's not good way as we have 100s of jobs 
with second script I am getting error. Error-

> Cannot index into a null array. At C:\Check status test.ps1:22 char:31
>   + $job = $server.JobServer.Jobs[ <<<< $job_to_check]
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CDSMaint:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Can anyone guide how I can have $job variable containing the object for job with name $job_to_check
Any hint,guidance is highly appreciated.

Script 1:

```
$sqlserver="server1"
#$job_to_check='Job1'
$script:username='user1'
$script:pass_word='password'    
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sqlserver;
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_login($username)
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_password($pass_word)
if ( $job_to_check -eq $null)
{
    Write-Host "Job is null"
}
$job = $server.JobServer.Jobs["Job1"]  
echo $job.Name
```

Script2:

```
$sqlserver="server1"
$job_to_check='Job1'
$script:username='user1'
$script:pass_word='password' 
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sqlserver;
$srv.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure=$false
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_login($username)
$srv.ConnectionContext.set_password($pass_word)
if ( $job_to_check -eq $null)
{
     Write-Host "Job is null"
}
$job = $server.JobServer.Jobs[$job_to_check]  
echo $job.Name
```

Comment: The error is telling you that $server.JobServer.Jobs is a null array, but it's impossible to tell from what you've posted why it might be null.  There's no other reference to $server.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why script 1 works but what I changed in script 2 (beside server name and login info) is the next to last line. 
From

```
$job = $server.JobServer.Jobs[$job_to_check]
```

To

```
$job = $srv.JobServer.Jobs[$job_to_check]
```

Comment: That was typo it should be

Comment: With that 1 change your script worked for me against a SQL 2008 R2 instance.  Are you sure the job in the $job_to_check variable exists on the server and spelling is exact?

Comment: Another point to check, if I purposely misspell the server name I get the same error message you posted.  I didn’t check for a problem with the login name or password but it’s also something to verify.

Comment: Spelling is correct and I can see its value also before I pass to Jobs and error is Cannot index into a null array.